# Git on multiple networks/offline sites

Tags: git, version-control

We are two teams who work on a single project. Each team is on a separate network. Unfortunately neither of these networks are connected to the Internet and no data is allowed to be transferred over the Internet for this project because of company rules. 
We could only transfer files from time to time between them, that's the only connection.

How could we maintain a Git repo while minimizing the data that needed to be transferred between sites?

Ideally, each team needs to be able to clone, commit and push to a bare repo on his network. Whenever we want to sync the repo we will transfer some kind of (binary?) diff/patch between the sites that will be used to sync the repos.

The method which is currently being used:
We have a single bare Git repo which is located on Network A. Team A is happy. Each time developers from network B want to sync their changes the are making series of paches from the last sync with the bare repo, give them to team A, team A is applaying the patches on the repo on network A. Sometimes we replace the bare repo from Network B with a copy of the repo from network A so the developers on network B could pull the changes.

What is wrong with this method?
1. We have the "up to date" repo only on site A. Team B need to create patches and apply them on site A in order to sync their work.
2. We transfer the whole repo between sites from time to time, not just the diffs  (whenever we want to pull on site B).
3. Developers from Site B are not pushing to the bare repo (only create patches for team A).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious solution would be to have a Git repository hosted online, which both locations can push/pull from.  This is the standard way, you could even use GitHub.

Comment: ,thanks for your answer! Unfortunately neither of these networks are connected to the Internet and no data is allowed to be transferred over the Internet for this project because of company rules. We could only transfer files from time to time between them, that's the only connection.